# strange issue when returning Ok() from nested controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

We have a rest interface which all works fine, but some customers wanted the ability to upload xml files via a portal.

I parse the file upload and then create the respective controller that would have been used if the data had been sent in the correct format via the rest interface.

Everything works, except an error message is returned from the nested controller to my ajax, ONLY if i return Ok();  which I find really weird. It must be quite late in the pipeline that something goes wrong, as I can't seem to catch any exception at all.

I've commented some code below with some example controllers to show what I mean.

```
public class FileController : ApiController
{
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
     {
           // if I return Ok(); from here it works fine..  so it's not the ajax
           // Get the file details
           var someParam = blah;
           var someData = blah;              

          try
          {
             var restController = new RestController();
             return await restController.SomeMethod(someParam, someData);
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
              // No error is ever caught here
              return new HttpExceptionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error uploading file");
          }
     }
}

public class RestController : ApiController 
{
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SomeMethod(someParam, someData)
     {
         // This returns fine
         return new HttpExceptionResult(HttpStatusCode.409, "Something already exists");            

         // this fails -> returns okay, but my ajax receives a 500 internal server error   
         return Ok();  
     }
}

public class HttpExceptionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _statusCode; 
    private readonly string _message;

    public HttpExceptionResult(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
    {
        _statusCode = statusCode;
        _message = message;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(_statusCode);
        response.Content = new StringContent(_message);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's a few things I could try to fix it straight off the bat (using my own class to return the 200 code), but i'd like to understand why this is happening internally. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisited this issue again to see if I can get around it, I only managed to find one way so far.

The trick appears to be passing the current ControllerContext to the new Controller.

```
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
    {
       var someParam = blah;
       var someData = blah;              
       try
       {
           var restController = new RestController()
           {
               ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext
           };

           // This now works
           return await restController.SomeMethod(someParam, someData);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           return new HttpExceptionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error uploading file");
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem